# kendo grid custom column menu

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo grid using the ASP.NET MVC wrappers with sorting, filtering and column menu enabled.  As I'm sure most of you know, there are two clickable actions in each column header:

- Clicking the title in the column header sorts the data in that column
- Clicking the column menu icon (chevron icon) displays the column menu options

This grid has a lot of columns so real estate is at a bit of a premium.  What I'd like to do is replace the sort action on the header text click with the column menu action.  Essentially, I want the title in each column header to take the place of the chevron icon.  When I click the header text in each column, I want the column menu options (sort asc, sort desc, columns, filter) instead of the sort.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is, I've not done it personally but I think it is just a case of removing the "k-icon", "k-i-arrow-n" and "k-i-arrow-s" classes from the column header link on the on click event. you may need to use the following in the event to make sure Kendo is done setting the icon.

```
setTimout(function(e){
    // remove classes
},1);
```

Hope this helps.